# GetDocumentUrlsById is not working in Load balance environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs

I am using the Document ID feature and in My code i want to fetch the Documentid url so i am using this method(**GetDocumentUrlsById** ). For this method we need to pass spsite and Documentid. I followed this and i was able to get it working in DEV machine (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/450288/Document-ID-Feature).

However when i moved to production it is not fetching the documentid url. My servers are load balanced.

It gives me an error "Index was out of bound" at this line

```
DocumentIdProvider provider = DocumentId.GetProvider(site); ;
    var result = provider.GetDocumentUrlsById(site, "DOCUMENT-4-1");
    Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

It gives me an error "Index was out of bound" at this line....

The document name is correct.but when i try to print the array length it gives me 0 as it count;

Not sure if any other way where in to fetch the Documentid url in load balanced servers.

Comment: Did the timer job run on the production environment by the time you ran your code? Also, is the DocumentID "DOCUMENT-4-1" hard coded in your code, or did you just simplify the code fragment for us? Does that DocumentID really exist, can you see it when you view the properties of the document?

Comment: yes i can view the document. Iam using lookup columns to fetch the id from shared document library. I have logged the document id in uls logs ,so iam sure iam getting doc id currently.when the above gets executed the length of the string array is 0.The same code is working in dev which is not load balanced